# Using a method reference to a generic method in a Base class gives me NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, java-8, method-reference

I have the below classes. When calling the `doSomething(...)` method with a lambda it works, but when using a method reference it gives me the below exception. Why? Is there anyway I can use method reference in this case?

Note:
I can not modify any of the code in the "lib" package.

**Edit**:

I'm using Eclipse to execute this:
Version: Neon Release (4.6.0)
Build id: 20160613-1800

Java version:
jdk1.8.0_102

```
package lib;
class Base<T> {
    public T m() {
        System.out.println("m");
        return thisInstance();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T thisInstance() {
        return (T) this;
    }
}
```

.

```
package lib;
public class Sub extends Base<Sub> {

}
```

.

```
package client;
import lib.Sub;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        Sub s1 = new Sub();
        doSomething(() -> s1.m());
        doSomething(s1::m);
    }

    interface Aaa {
        void f();
    }

    public static void doSomething(Aaa a) {
        a.f();
    }
}
```

When running the Client.main() method I get the following output:

```
m
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: lib.Sub.m()Llib/Sub;
    at client.Client.main(Client.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: lib.Sub.m()Llib/Sub;
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:977)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:1002)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:1390)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandles.java:1746)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:477)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: I think, in this case, it’s Eclipse to blame. While `javac` had similar method-reference related bugs, this specific example works with `javac` of `jdk1.8.0_77`. So you will have to update Eclipse.

Comment: Updated to jdk1.8.102. Still same problem. Will try to update to Eclipse Neon.

Comment: Updated to Eclipse Neon with jdk1.8.102, still same problem.

Comment: You may verify with `javac` that the JDK itself doesn’t have this problem (as said, with `8u77`, it works) and open a bug report at Eclipse—or wait a bit patiently as Eclipse developers are reading here…

Comment: True, sporadically I pick up issues from here :). Still it would help the process if the OP reports it at bugs.eclipse.org (preferably with a link back to this question, actually).

Comment: I'll do that asap.

Comment: Bug reported. See: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=500374